# Is there any relationship between Train error and Test error in linear regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, regularization, linear, train

I am doing regularization on linear regression and am observing something arguable: By increasing the $\lambda$ (shrinkage value), I observe that there is a point in which the training and testing error are the same. I just wonder if there is any justification behind this.